# Problems with labels while using Value relation

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm using the value relation widget to populate fields from a `.csv`-table with values corresponding to a chosen value.

I don't know why, but the label caption displayed on the map is showing the key column and not the value which is related. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using the `current_value()` filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to label your layer with an expression (click the Epsilon symbol to the right of the 'Label with' drop down menu in layer properties, under the labels tab).

[image]

In the expression builder dialog, enter the following expression:

```
attribute(get_feature('VALUE_LAYER_NAME', 'KEY_FIELD', KEY), 'VALUE_FIELD')
```

Where:

`VALUE_LAYER_NAME` is the name of the layer having the value column (your csv table)

`KEY_FIELD` is the name of the key column in your csv layer

`KEY` is the name of the field in your spatial layer which your are populating from the csv

`VALUE_FIELD` is the name of the column in the csv table which contains the values

Comment: that's doing the trick! I still don't understand why it just worked in an older project. values were stored into the new created value and displayed just by using this column.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using now, and what version were you using for the old project? It was probably a change in how the value relation widget works - review the changelogs if you really want to know when the change happened. (If you do, please add that information to your question - it would be useful for others with the same issue.)