# Using resolved values as a label in child table using only the defined Value Relation

Tags: qgis, labeling, relation

I have a "Value Relation" defined to a parent table from a child one in QGIS 3.34.3:

[image]

The attribute table shows the resolved value (species name) correctly:

[image]

Same when I use the "Identify Features" tool:

[image]

But I cannot use that resolved field as a **label**: the "species_id" field available is rendered as the original numerical value.

Is it possible to display a label using the resolved value, without a join?
Or is the join the only way to properly display the label?

This solution works:

```
attribute(get_feature('bush_species', 'id', species_id), 'species')
```

Source: [Problems with labels while using Value relation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337190/problems-with-labels-while-using-value-relation)

But for maintenance, I have now to worry about two different places where the relation is build. I wish I could simply tick a box "☐ Also use related value for labeling" when defining the "Value Relation".

Comment: You can try to use represent_value("species_id") in the label expression. I guess that should fix your problem.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396122/92434

Comment: Yes it also does, but same thing as the other solution I found: e.g. if the db field changes, one has to update the QGIS project in two places. This is a little error prone, imho.

Comment: Could you not use `species` as both the Key and Value column in your Value Relation widget? That would be the easiest... 

Otherwise it's probably not a good idea for your target layer `species_id` field to change names anyway, since you would need to manually recreate the widget every time that happens. 

Still, if a field name is referred to multiple times across a project, you could consider storing the name as a project variable (either manual string input or an expression to get matching column name from layer based on pattern), referring to that variable in `attribute()` etc.